# Jmeter how to override csv file of View result tree?

Tags: csv, jmeter

So, I have a Jmeter jmx file that, I execute by the command line and the result is automatically exported for a CSV file, I have an assertion of type View Result Tree where I defined the CSV. My problem is that if I execute with the GUI the Jmeter ask to override the CSV file that is the behavior that I expected, however executing the Jmeter by the command line the Jmeter don't override the CSV, it appends the results to the existing file. How can I define to override the CSV instead of appending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using   -n -t and -l command line argument jmeter .csv file can be written.
here is the below example:

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
```

Try out -f command line argument to remove data from .csv file and then add new data

Try out this here is example:

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -f -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
```

For more information

[Full List of CommandLine Option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Answer (score 3):

The GUI mode behavior is controllable by the following JMeter property:

```
resultcollector.action_if_file_exists
```

The possible values are:

- `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=ASK` - what you have now
- `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=APPEND` - new results will be added to the existing file
- `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=DELETE` - the existing file will be overwritten with the new results

Just add the line which corresponds your expectations to *user.properties* file and restart JMeter to pick up the change.

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference - Miscellaneous configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

Be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) it is not recommended to run JMeter in GUI mode and use listeners, especially the View Results Tree